# Decimals after multiplying values in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an app that multiplies a number for a price that can be decimal or not. For example 3 * 3.50.

I'm using Swift 3. I searched for several topics here but could not add this feature to my app.

My code looks like this:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var valueBreja1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var quantityBreja1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalBreja1: UILabel!

    @IBAction func calcBreja1(_ sender: Any) {
        let a = Int(valueBreja1.text!)
        let b = Int(quantityBreja1.text!)

        let Answer = a! + b!
        totalBreja1.text = "R$\(Answer)"
    }
```

I wanted to show the value with decimal number after multiplication.

Comment: There is no multiplication in your code. There is only an adition. If you would like to show a value as currency you should use `NumberFormatter` and set the numberStyle to `.currency`

Comment: `Int` stands for "integer"... which can only be whole numbers. You'll probably want to use [`Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal) for prices

Comment: @ViniciusPV Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double` instead of `Int`:

```
@IBAction func calcBreja1(_ sender: Any) {

    let a = Double(valueBreja1.text!)
    let b = Double(quantityBreja1.text!)

    let Answer = a! + b!
    totalBreja1.text = "R$\(Answer)"

}
```

Comment: Don't use `Double` for currency. You'll have a bad, bad time.

Comment: Sorry, kind of new to Swift. May I ask why?

Comment: Nothing to do with Swift, it's equally applicable to any other language. E.g. in Java, `BigInteger` is usually used. The issue is that `Double` has really pesky precision issues that stem from it being based on binary floating point, as opposed to the decimal floating point humans usually expect. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3141234

Comment: `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` -> `false`. See for for yourself inthe Swift repl: `0.1 + 0.2` -> `$R0: Double = 0.30000000000000004` and `0.3` -> `$R1: Double = 0.29999999999999999`

Comment: Humans are used to `1/3` being `0.333...`, but they're not so used to `7 / 10` being `0.69999999999999996`

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the input. I'll look into it more.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, you're creating `Int` values from the field strings. `Int` values can only hold integer values, so any fractional portion will be discarded. You need to create `Double` values (or some other form of floating or fractional value).

To format the output use a formatter.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

var str1 = "3.50"
var str2 = "3"
if let value = Double(str1) {
    if let multiplier = Int(str2) {
        let formattedResult = String(format: "%.02f", value*Double(multiplier))
    }
}
```